# How to change row height of TableView on the fly?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'd like to change the row height of JavaFX TableView when user selects/deselects a CheckBox. The only way I could find is via CSS, so I tried:

```
if (someCheckBox.isSelected())
    tableView.setStyle(".table-row-cell {-fx-cell-size: 60px;}");
else
    tableView.setStyle(".table-row-cell {-fx-cell-size: 20px;}");
```

But this does not work. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out that the JavaFX 8 introduces **setFixedCellSize** property, which meets my requirements as I need all rows to have the same height. So this is the solution:

```
if (someCheckBox.isSelected())
    tableView.setFixedCellSize(60.0);
else
    tableView.setFixedCellSize(20.0);
```

Comment: This will change the height of all the rows, how to change the height of a row, on which user has clicked. and other rows should not get affected, because user has not clicked on other rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution of this problem (it's only first "Workaround", but "hight works fine):

```
column8.setCellFactory(column -> {
        return new TableCell<Anfrage, Set<Email>>() /*Or whathever you have*/ {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Set<Email> item, boolean empty) {                    
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText("");
                } else {                           
                    VBox graphic = new VBox();
                    if (item.size()>1) {
                        List<Email> sortedMailsList = new ArrayList<>();
                        sortedMailsList.addAll(item);
                        Collections.sort(sortedMailsList, new Comparator<Email>(){
                            @Override
                            public int compare(Email o1, Email o2) {
                                if (o1.getEmailVersandt() != null) {
                                    if (o2.getEmailVersandt() != null) {
                                        return o1.getEmailVersandt().compareTo(o2.getEmailVersandt());
                                    } else {
                                        return 1;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if (o2.getEmailVersandt() != null) {
                                        return -1;
                                    } else {
                                        return 0;
                                    }
                                }                                    
                            }                                
                        });
                        sortedMailsList.stream().forEach((emailObj) -> {
                            graphic.getChildren().add((new Label(emailObj.toString())));
                        });
                    } else {
                        for (Email emailObj : item) {
                            graphic.getChildren().add((new Label(emailObj.toString())));
                        }
                    }                        
                    this.setMaxHeight(20.0*item.size());
                    setGraphic(graphic);                         
                }
            }                                
        };                       
    });
```

For me it's also sort "Mails" (Date field which is nullable), but i think you don't need it. 
Main points are: 
1. Set cell factory
2. Set height in "updateItem".
And that's it:)

[image]